# How can I display the first 100 characters of a blog post that was written using rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am making a blog where the blog content is written using rich text editor. Before using rich text editor I used `substring` to display the first 100 characters but now since the rich text that is coming from my api is coming as an array, I cant show the initial lines of the blog post.
I am using Sanity for CMS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

import { client } from '../../client'

import PortableText from "react-portable-text"

import BlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react"

const Blog = () => {

    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        const query = '*[_type == "blog"] | order(publishedAt desc)'

        

        client.fetch(query)

        .then((data) => {

            console.log('before',data[0])

            setBlogs(data);

        })

    }, [])

    

 return (

    <div>

          <div style={{marginTop: "3rem"}} className='center top-name'>

            BLOGS

          </div>

        <div class="blog_post">

            

            {blogs.map((blog, index) => (

                

                <div key={index} class="container_copy2">                        

                <Link

                    style={{textDecoration: "none"}}

                    to={`/blog/${blog.slug.current}`}>

                        <div>

                            <h1 class="blog-title">{blog.title}</h1>

                            <p class="blog-content">

                                

                                <BlockContent

                                blocks={blog.content}

                                projectId= {process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}

                                dataset="production"

                                />



 </p>

                        </div>

                        

                </Link>

                <hr style={{color: "white", width: "500px", opacity: "0.2", marginTop: "2rem", marginBottom: "0px"}} />

                    </div>

            ))}

            

        </div>

    </div>

  )
```

[image]

i tried using substring again but since its an array it wont work

Comment: What are the contents of the array? Is the blog content a string within a single element of the array, or is the blog content different strings across many elements in the array?

Comment: i added a picture of the structure of content pleaase check it out

Answer (score 0):

using the serializers prop to customize the rendering of the block type then wrapping the text content of the block in a p tag with a class of blog-content and using substring(0, 100) to display only the first 100 characters of the block's text content.

```
<BlockContent
  blocks={blog.content.slice(0, 1)}
  projectId={process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}
  dataset="production"
  serializers={{
    types: {
      span: ({ children }) => (
      <span>{children[0].text.substring(0, 100)}...</span>
      ),
    },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: hey i think you are close but i am still getting an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
"  butif i put this "{props.children[0]}" i get the initial  few words, any idea?

Comment: This answer is close. `children[0].text` only returns “Lorem ispum” while the rest of the words span the children. First, combine all of the text by `let text = ''` and `children.reduce((text, i) => text + i.text, text)`, then use substring on `text`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the client side, then another option is CSS [line-clamp](https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp). This way, you won't need to compute the character count and the browser will do it automatically for you.

```css
p {
  width: 250px;

  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam finibus sem a pellentesque feugiat. Nunc lobortis enim erat, quis molestie nunc ultrices a. Vestibulum scelerisque vulputate faucibus. Sed maximus ex a purus suscipit, at finibus urna mollis. Pellentesque commodo maximus consectetur. Sed bibendum vulputate fringilla. Praesent bibendum, nisl a pulvinar efficitur, metus nisl consectetur ligula, ac bibendum augue velit ac libero. Quisque et vehicula velit. Vestibulum porta massa vel tellus semper sodales. Curabitur aliquet maximus cursus. Curabitur et ullamcorper velit.
</p>
```